# Its possible to create a markdown report from a template that contains multiple files from shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

Hi and thanks for reading me. Im working on a shiny app that renders a markdown report and I discover some html templates that I think look great, but when I tried to make a connection between the shiny app and the markdown document, I get an error message like: `Warning in file.create(to[okay]) : cannot create file '/var/folders/9t/w6t7k1zj0_bf2wsqktgnmb1r0000gn/T//RtmpoXq8XC//ejemplo reporte/ejemplo reporte.Rmd', reason 'No such file or directory'`. Basically I have the shiny project, and then inside I have another folder with the markdown and their template components, that looks like:

[image]

and inside the folder "ejemplo reporte" I have the markdown files, that looks like:

[image]

For the shiny app code, is the following:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    add_busy_spinner(spin = "cube-grid"),
    sliderInput("slider", "Slider", 1, 100, 50),
    numericInput("perro", "perro", value = 4, min = 1, max = 10),
    downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$report <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "report.pdf",
      content = function(file) {
        tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "ejemplo reporte/ejemplo reporte.Rmd")
        file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
        
        params <- list(n = input$slider,
                       plot = input$perro
        )
        
        rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                          params = params,
                          envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
        )
      }
    )
    
    
  }
)
```

Is there a way to connect this shiny app to the markdown folder and the markdown file?

Thanks for the help

Comment: one issue may be the fact that your folder has spaces. Replace the spaces in your rmd and folder with an under score or dash. Also what error are you seeing?

Comment: I changed the filename for "report/report.Rmd" but I still getting the same error message: `Warning in file.create(to[okay]) :
  cannot create file '/var/folders/9t/w6t7k1zj0_bf2wsqktgnmb1r0000gn/T//RtmpoXq8XC//report/report.Rmd', reason 'No such file or directory'`

Comment: Is the function called in the same folder as `report.Rmd`?

Comment: No, the shiny application code is located outside the folder with the markdowm file